# Ingress sends traffic to the domain root

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a workload which is exposed through `NodePort` service with the name `online-forms-lib-service`. This workload has the `/version` route.

Also I have the following ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: online-forms-lib-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /formslib/
```

The problem is, the `/version` route is not available at:

```
example.com/formslib/version
```

How to solve this?

**Update**

It goes to the application root when I call:

```
example.com/formslib/
```

Adding any path from there directs me to the default backend

**Update**
Added the annotation:

```
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

Still the same behaviour.

Comment: Can you share the full ingress object, along with the ingress controller you are using?

Comment: @UtkuÖzdemir Updated with the full yaml of my ingress. What is ingress controller?

Comment: Ingress controllers are kind of proxy servers that run on the cluster, read the ingress objects on the cluster and configure layer 7 (http) routing based on the ingress rules. Popular ones are nginx ing. controller, traefik, ambassador and so on.
Also, if you are using a Google Cloud managed Kubernetes cluster (GKE), it comes with a built-in ingress controller, which creates Load Balancer objects in Google Cloud project for each ingress.

Comment: Dou you want to expose /version backend in your ingress as /formslib/version? If that's the case, you need the rewrite target annotation, check the example here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout

Comment: @bserdar I just did. But it still goes to the default backend

Comment: That example above would only work if nginx was used as the ingress controller - see the annotation: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target`. That's why I asked which ingress controller you are using - they behave differently, work with different annotations etc.

Comment: @UtkuÖzdemir Not sure which ingress controller I use. I have the workload, service and ingress I'm trying to create - thats all. Thanks.

Comment: I added `ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` - but no use.

Comment: Of course since you are using annotations: ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: / no matter what you add to example.com/whatever will be rewritten to / once the rule in the ingress has been matched. The way I solve this is to use a proxy in between.

Ingress-controller -> proxy -> kubernetes-service -> Deployment/pod

Comment: @RodrigoLozaCan you please elaborate on your method little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by the [rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) annotations.

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

As of September, 2019, the GKE ingress doesn't support the `rewrite` rules.

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/109

And no published plans for implementing it either.

The only solution is nginx or other 3rd party ingress controller which supports rewrite annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress) resource mostly relies on the [Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) implemented in K8s cluster with the aim to propagate Ingress rules and supplying load-balancing and traffic routing features.

As @ Utku Özdemir mentioned in the comment, most of the cloud providers on the market propose native Ingress controllers support, i.e. [Ingress-gce](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce) in *Google Cloud*, making possible to create External [HTTP(S) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) via particular Ingress resource.

In addition, you might find a lot of third party Ingress controllers [solutions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/#additional-controllers), that can potentially expand *L7 network traffic* functionality depending on the client needs.

I've checked your current Ingress configuration in a similar scenario, and I've managed a proper sub-path routing adopting wildcard `*` matching rule, preceding the root application path for the particular backend service:

```
- backend:
    serviceName: online-forms-lib-service
    servicePort: 80
    path: /formslib/*
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your time for writing about this. I have added the real issue and marked as the answer. And +1 for you.